# parsing string in mysql and get the date

Tags: mysql, parsing, date

Does anyone here know how to parse string in mysql?

I have a column which value is in string.

**example**

```
movie1view_2014_01_01
movie2view_2014_05_02_part1
```

I want to get only the date that is this example `2014_01_01` and `2014_05_02`  and convert it into `date`.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr You should check Google before posting a question like this on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can do

```
select replace(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'_',4),'_',-3),'_','-') as
date
from test
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f0a5/6)**